# Wide to long format pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Desired Output -

| id | gender | random_genre |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | F | fiction |
| 1 | F | history |
| 2 | M | mystery |
| 3 | F | fiction |
| 4 | M | history |

I have a dataframe where a user can have multiple preferences and I have to join these with some other kind of preferences which makes the table exponentially large. Like x, y etc. preferences are up to 80+ of one kind and almost 40 are of another kind.

Until now I was pivoting the table (`pivot_table`) and performing merge but I want to use the output for charts (count of a preference etc.).

Current output after pivot_table -

| id | gender | fiction | history | mystery |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | F | 1 | NaN | NaN |
| 1 | F | NaN | 2 | NaN |
| 2 | M | NaN | NaN | 3 |
| 3 | F | 1 | NaN | NaN |
| 4 | M | NaN | 2 | NaN |

Having almost 80+ preferences of just one type and more after joining.

How can I convert all these back after joins to the first table, where I just **have a single column for all the preferences and if an id has multiple preferences a new row is created for the same**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after pivot, melt as follows

```
 df.melt(id_vars=['id','gender'], value_vars=['fiction','history','mystery']).dropna()



     id gender variable  value
0    1      F  fiction    1.0
3    3      F  fiction    1.0
6    1      F  history    2.0
9    4      M  history    2.0
12   2      M  mystery    3.0
```

Comment: Thanks, give us a sample dataframe with more entries and expected output. May use this link as guide to give a clearer question https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Good, that is the desired output. Where is the original dataset?Can you give us the sample dataset from which we will derive desired output?

Comment: See my edits and see if thats what you are after. Happy to help further

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `pandas.melt` function. It might do the trick for you